# Query nested values with DynamoDB in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I have a DynamoDB table, an Item has the following structure:

```
{
  pickup: "Florida",
  tonnage: {
    "3ton": {
      type: {
        nonrefrigerated: [...],
        refrigerated: [...]
      },
      "5ton": {
        type: {
            nonrefrigerated: [...],
            refrigerated: [...]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am able to get an Item by key like this:

```
function getData(callback) {
  let params = {
    TableName: "Locations",
    Key: {
      pickup: "Florida"
    }
  };

  db.get(params, function(err, data) {
    callback(err, data);
  });
}
```

But how do I query the nested data? the AWS documentation is not clear on that. For example, how can I Query:

```
Select from Locations WHERE pickup='Florida' AND tonnage='5ton' AND Type='nonrefrigerated'
```

Comment: Short answer is - what you are trying to do is not possible with DynamoDB. I suggest you stream your data from DynamoDB to Elasticsearch where you can do this type of querying.

Comment: Yeah, can't do that with dynamoDB. You could also use DocumentDB which is aws' take on mongoDB